# Optimize MySQL query with more than 100 thousand records

Tags: php, mysql

I would like you to help me optimize this query.

```
SELECT  carrier,
        SUM(views) AS views,
        SUM(views-1) AS repeated,
        SUM(views >= 1) AS unique_views,
        COUNT(1) AS total
    FROM  stats s1
    WHERE  id_link = 39
      AND  EXISTS (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  stats s2
            where  id_link = 39
              AND  s2.carrier = s1.carrier
            LIMIT  1, 1 )
    GROUP BY  carrier
    HAVING  COUNT(1) >= 1
    LIMIT  1,1
 UNION 
 SELECT  'TOTAL' AS carrier,
        SUM(views) AS views,
        SUM(views-1) AS repeated,
        SUM(views >= 1) AS unique_views,
        COUNT(1) AS total
    FROM  stats s4
    WHERE  id_link = 39
      AND  EXISTS (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  stats s3
            where  s3.carrier = s4.carrier
            LIMIT  1, 1 )
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE `stats` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_link` int(11) NOT NULL,
`country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`views` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`asn` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`carrier` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`device` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`browser` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
`referrer` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_link` (`id_link`),
CONSTRAINT `stats_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_link`) REFERENCES `campaigns` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=614606 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I'm creating a web traffic tracker.
I have a table called "stats" where I keep; VIEWS, ASN, IP, BROWSER, DEVICE and other things, among those things is the "carrier", that is, the internet service provider

What I want is to see how many visits there are from each carrier, accounts are repeated more than once, how many unique visits there are.

The code I have already does what I want but it only works when there are few records, now that I have more than 100k records the server crashes, it does not load the query and I even have to restart apache.

Here I leave an illustrative image only

[image]

Is there any way to speed up that query?

Thank you in advance for your comments and help.

Comment: For anyone to be able to help you here, we would need way more info, like the schema of all the tables involved, example data and all the indexes. It's pretty hard to help optimize a query if you don't know anything about the source.

Comment: Hi, I have added the table structure, only the "stats" table is involved

Comment: You want to know if there are at least 2 rows??    `EXISTS ( ... LIMIT 1,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** `views` is used as if it is a number.  If that is the case, don't use `VARCHAR`.  Suggest `INT UNSIGNED` (which tops out at 4 billion).

** Use reasonable limits instead of `varchar(1000)`.

** Smaller is somewhat faster.  So...  Normalize oft-repeated columns.  `carrier` has about 9 distinct values?  A `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` would take only 2 bytes, and have more than enough room to handle the universe of carriers.  Ditto for most of the `varchar(1000)`.

** Suggest using the standard 2-letter "country_code" (`CHAR(2)`) instead of `country(100)` -- IN, US, UK, FR, ...

** Specificaly for speeding up the query, change

```
KEY `id_link` (`id_link`),
```

to

```
KEY `id_link` (`id_link`, carrier),
```

** Look into using `WITH ROLLUP` with the `GROUP BY` so you don't need the `UNION` and second `SELECT`.

** Consider building and maintaining a "Summary Table" that has daily subtotals.  Querying against this table will be much faster than against the raw ("Fact") table that you currently have.  More info: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables .  (This expands on what Shubham mentioned in a Comment.)

Answer (score 1):

you can achive it using Mysql OffSet and LIMIT

you can try using ajax, at first load 1500 records, on scroll OR by clicking on next load next 1500 records, use datatables, it has internal pagination + additinal next button for more result,
eg on
1st page offset = 0, limit = 1500
2nd page offset = 1500 , limit 1500 .. and so on

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that here I am not looking to show data and now, that of the pagination I understand, but in this case I am doing calculations that must necessarily go through all the data in the table, so the pagination is what less

Comment: add one more table, that only keeps math of your table like,  someone visited website using AT&T > your normal insert program runs as usual, but in that new table AT&T 's columns Value increases >>>> so while making calculation it will speed up >> and if any new carrier found new table will add one more column and keep its math

Comment: hope you are getting this, whenever visitor hits your keep count of visit >> and at time of  your operation computer will deal with few big values, instead of thousand of small values

Comment: I doubt if there are more than 1500 "carriers".

Comment: until 4000 there is no problem still, there is other way like make json arrays, every visit will edit/create json array [{"Carrier Name":"AT & T", "Device":"Samsung","IP":"80.80.80",},{...so on}]